# How to create mini-batches for non-image data in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to load my training and testing data

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5, ), (0.5, ))])

trainset = datasets.FashionMNIST('~/.pytorch/F_MNIST_data/', download=True, train=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)


testset = datasets.FashionMNIST('~/.pytorch/F_MNIST_data/', download=True, train=False, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

I see the implementation for image data is there a way to load non-image data in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `torch.utils.data` module for this by using the following steps,

1. Create a Dataset class to load custom data by inheriting `torch.utils.data.Dataset`
2. Create the dataset object by passing the data to the instance of the custom Dataset class
3. Use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` to load the dataset and obtain the batches

assuming you have loaded the data from the directory, in train and test numpy arrays, you can inherit from `torch.utils.data.Dataset` class to create your dataset object

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(MyDataset, self).__init__()
        assert x.shape[0] == y.shape[0] # assuming shape[0] = dataset size
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def __len__(self):
        return self.y.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]
```

Then, create your dataset object

```
traindata = MyDataset(train_x, train_y)
```

Finally, use `DataLoader` to create your mini-batches

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(traindata, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```